# Translate influx stddev to promQL

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

what would be the best way to write this influx query in promQL?

```
SELECT Stddev(value) FROM db WHERE cat = 'time' AND metricName = 'CPU Time' AND (server='s1' OR server='s2') AND time > now() - 1h GROUP BY server
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) query in VictoriaMetrics starting from v1.56.0:

```
histogram_stddev(
  sum(
    histogram_over_time(
      db_value{cat="time",metric_name="CPU Time",server=~"s1|s2"}[1h]
    )
  ) by (vmrange,server)
)
```

This query must be sent to `/api/v1/query` handler.